# How can I use transform variable right away without GetComponent<Transform>( )?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Can we use 'transform' variable right away without typing
`Transfrom transform = GetComponent<Transform>();`
Because a script inherits from `MonoBehaviour` which inherits from `Behaviour` which inherits from `Component` where "transform variable" is declared?

[image]
[image]

If my guess is true then why can't I use collider2D variable right away like transform? even though it is declared in component class like transform variable and how can I use gameObject variable right away like transform?

Answer (score 2):

`Transform` can (and probably should) be accessed via the property because it is a default component on every `GameObject` and thus should be valid at all times.

Also, [the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html) indicate that it should be used directly.

---

Your second question regarding the other properties:

There was a time where you could access all the other components via property, but internally they just wrapped around `GetComponent<T>()` and since it is better to cache them in your own code, they all got deprecated.

So, you should use `transform` when you want to access a `GameObject`s `Transform` component, but you must not use the others, they just exist for historical reasons and compatibility.

Back in the day, Unity released a blog post for this topic: [Unity 5: API changes & automatic script updating](https://blog.unity.com/technology/unity5-api-changes-automatic-script-updating)